# I'm working with MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, configuration

I create a new user

> CREATE USER 'new_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';

But the user have all privileges and I don't use GRANT for that.

How can I create a user without privileges?

Comment: What use is a user with zero privileges?

Comment: My crystal ball says: You are trying that in a database with a name that has 2 `T`s in it.

Comment: Because I want to use GRANT for specific privileges for the user. I don't want that the user can access to all databases or schemas in the server.

Comment: He doesn't. How did you conclude that the newly created user would have access to all databases or schemas? (My crystal ball knows that, but you could also add the information yourself).